# Faster way of applying `all` function?

Tags: r, vectorization, sapply

Suppose i have a logical array :

```
dimensions = c(10,100,200,300)
x = runif(prod(dimensions))>0.3
dim(x) = dimensions
```

Is there a faster way to get the result :

```
y = colMeans(apply(x,2:4,all))
```

?

Apply is quite slow, and this use case is quite straightforward, hence i wander...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `colSums`:

```
system.time(
  y <- colMeans(apply(x,2:4,all))
  )
# user      system     elapsed 
#6.916       0.058       6.978 

system.time(
z <- colMeans(colSums(x, dims = 1) == dim(x)[1])
)
# user      system     elapsed 
#0.117       0.000       0.117

identical(y, z)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Stunning. Thanks a lot. By the way, do you know why it is so much faster?

Comment: @lrnv Function calls are very expensive. `all` is a primitive function, so this would be even worse with a closure if it was called that often. This answer substitutes 100*200*300 + 1 function calls with four function calls (if I count them correctly).